# Apache Wordpress Link

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have installed Apache and WordPress on a Ubuntu VM. In general it works, but every time I go on the web page with the browser (http://www.example.com/), the address is automatically changed to http://www.example.com/wp/.

How do I have to change the config, so that the address in the browser will remain http://www.example.com/` and not http://www.example.com/wp/?

Comment: it could be a WP setting, an Apache config rule, an .htaccess, a subdirectory... explain better your setup. Did you install WP on a subdirectory and now you want to hide the "wp" part of the url?

Comment: I didn't make any changes in the wp settings and I don't use a .htaccess-file. It was a default installation. How do I know if installed WP on a subdirectory?

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed your WordPress in subdirectory and if you want to move it to root directory, you can refer WordPress codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: do not post link only answers. Improve your answer by adding some description about the procedure and then the link

Comment: I don't post any other third party link. It is official WordPress.org link and it is well documented on how to properly migrate a WordPress blog. I don't think it is inappropriate in any way.

Comment: link could change in the future. I didn't say it's inappropriate, I said to add some excerpt of the link in your answer, so when a future user comes here, and that link maybe won't work anymore, he will have some more info to search further

Comment: I never seen old WordPress codex links are broken and I am sure WordPress community is aware about their URLs. Did you ever see any broken WordPress codex link?